# Heroku db:migrate says a column that does not exist does not exist and recommends renaming it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I ran:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

And the error is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "book" does not exist
```

And it recommends:

```
: ALTER TABLE "books" RENAME COLUMN "book" TO "want"
```

"books" is a table. "want" is a column of that table.

This is printed three times.

My schema:

```rb
  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "want"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.text "starting"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_books_on_user_id"
  end
```

In the middle of the error, it says:

```
/app/db/migrate/20190801032030_change_book_book_column_name.rb:3:in `change'
```

This is something I used long time ago to change the column name. The content is:

```
  def change
    rename_column :books, :book, :want
  end
```

I can't remember what I may have done with this so that I am getting this error now. Can you please help?

**UPDATE**

Frustrated, I deleted that migration file. Then I ran again. This time, I got this error:

```
Table 'posts' has no foreign key for {:to_table=>"books", :column=>"books_id"}
```

It also mentions a file:

```
/app/db/migrate/20190806222313_remove_book_ref_to_posts.rb:3:in `change'
```

Whose content is:

```
  def change
    remove_reference :posts, :books, foreign_key: true
  end
```

Schema for posts:

```rb
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "book_id"
    t.index ["book_id"], name: "index_posts_on_book_id"
  end
```

...what can I do?

Comment: Delete that migration too and, if you want the FK, add a new migration to add it. Then clean up the mess by deleting all your old migrations (really, migrations aren't meant to be forever, migrations are meant to get you from A to B so you don't need them once everything is at B and rollbacks are rarely successful after more changes have been made). Looks like your dev version, your Heroku version, and your Heroku database got a bit out of sync.

Comment: @muistooshort I just got it to work. (deleted that thing, deleted the column want, and then created a new migration adding want, then deleted that migration which deleted the column want). Thank you for the comment. I'm happy to choose yours as answer if you want to post it.

Comment: @muistooshort Also do you know why icons might not show in deployment? if there can be many answers, I'll write a question.

Comment: I'm happy with just a comment so you could convert your "I kept deleting migrations until it worked" comment to an answer and go with that. The icon issue sounds like a new question to me.

Comment: @muistooshort OK, thank you. I posted a new question here regarding the icons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564946/ui-different-icons-are-not-showing-in-deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happens for (at least) two different reasons:

- The column / table was renamed manually using a SQL client, by connecting directly to the database
- The migration `20190806222313_remove_book_ref_to_posts` was deployed and "migrated", but you somewhat updated the file and re-deployed to Heroku.

For the first point, I suggest to not update the database schema outside a migration. This makes your application being outside the [12 factors](https://12factor.net/) scope, which makes replayability hard (a key point for 12 factors applications). For example, if you re-deploy your application to a new environment and a new database, you would have to run the migrations once, see them fails, re-do the manual schema update you did on your previous database, then run again the migrations. Very painful.

For the second point, I've learned the hard way and have been in this situation more than once in the past. Here is what I do now that is 100% effective:

1. If you work with multiple branches, and deploy a specific branch to Heroku for testing, always rollback first your database migrations. (heroku run rails db:rollback STEP=XXX) where STEP is the number of migrations to be rollbacked.
2. NEVER update a migration file once it's been deployed or shared with a co-worker. It makes re-playing the previous migration painful and can introduce downtime.
3. If you are in one of 1) or 2) situation **and you still need to re-run the migration for any reason**, you will have to manually remove the corresponding row in the table `schema_migrations`. This table has a single column which is the ID of all the migrations that were applied (migrated) to your database. 
   So, let's say I have the migration file "123_my_migration.rb" that I deployed to Heroku and migrated, a new row will exists in the `schema_migrations` table with `123` as value. It means that your migration will never be executed again, unless you remove this row from the table.

It's a bit of discipline, but once you got it, you will really enjoy every minute of your discipline and will be confident enough with every deployment and migration you have to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete that migration also and then creating another migration to delete the existing want column, and then creating another migration to create a new want column, and then deleting that migration which deleted the want column. Basically getting rid of all discrepancies -- giving no excuse for Heroku to say a column doesn't exist.