# UI different -- Icons are not showing -- in deployment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my rails app, icons are not showing in deployment. And it's not just that icons are not showing. When I exclude icons from my app in development, only icons are missing. In deployment, where icons should be are the popup boxes that would have appeared by clicking on the icons in question. In menu, when I exclude icon, the item that should be far right is far left, below other items, messing up the whole UI. Something is going on, and I don't know what that is.

I'm using UIKit. I've downloaded and added its CSS, JS, and icons files in asset/stylesheet and asset/javascript.

Because icons were not working in development only with this arrangement, I included in the head:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
```

Then the icons were showing in development.

I'm not really sure what could be different. I've run

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

And it hasn't helped.

I also tried downloading the icons folder and placing it in my asset/images and calling it from the header. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was the add CDN link (UIKit) for javascript. Now icons are showing and it's working fine in production.

**BUT** why does simply dropping JS, CSS, and icon.js files in asset not work in production but work just fine in development? Although, I should mention that icon.js file was not working and I had to add a CDN link for it in the header.

I'd really appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I SCP'd uikit-icons.min.js to my servers public/asset directory, it worked after that.